# HTML How to position a button relative to two divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two tables that I have placed in two divs which divide the screen vertically in two half's. These tables have collapsible rows that can expand on click.

At the bottom of the tables, I have placed a submit button which is positioned relative in div1. So when the table in div1 expands, the button moves down as expected. But when table in div2 expands, the button stays at it's position.

My question is, can I make this button relative to both the divs so it should move when any table, either from div1 or div2 expands.

```js
addPlusSign();
$(".btn1").click(function() {
  $(".expand1").toggle();
  var btn1Text = $(".btn1").text();
  if (btn1Text.indexOf("+") > -1) {
    var temp = btn1Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '-');
    $(".btn1").text(temp);
  } else if (btn1Text.indexOf("-") > -1) {
    var temp = btn1Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '+');
    $(".btn1").text(temp);
  }
});
$(".btn2").click(function() {
$(".expand2").toggle();
var btn1Text = $(".btn2").text();
if (btn2Text.indexOf("+") > -1) {
  var temp = btn2Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '-');
  $(".btn2").text(temp);
} else if (btn2Text.indexOf("-") > -1) {
  var temp = btn2Text.replace(/\+|\-/ig, '+');
  $(".btn2").text(temp);
}
});
})

function addPlusSign() {
  if ($(".expand1")) {
    var btn1Text = $(".btn1").text();
    $(".btn1").text(btn1Text + " [+]");
  }
  if ($(".expand2")) {
    var btn2Text = $(".btn2").text();
    $(".btn2").text(btn1Text + " [+]");
  }
}
$(function() {
  $('.admin-form')
    //we need to save values from all inputs with class 'admin-input'
    .find(':input.admin-input')
    .each(function() {
      //save old value in each input's data cache
      $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val())
    })
    .end()
    .submit(function(ev) {
      var changed = false;
      $(':input.admin-input', this).filter(function() {
        if ($(this).val() != $(this).data('oldValue')) {
          changed = true;
        }
      });
      if ($(this).hasClass('changed') && (!changed)) {
        alert("None of the thresholds were changed!");
        ev.preventDefault()
      }
      if ($(this).hasClass('changed') && changed) {
        var allowSubmit = window.confirm("You have set a unique threshold for one or more sub-elements below. Are you sure you want to reset them all?")
        if (!allowSubmit)
          ev.preventDefault()
      }
    });
});
$(document).on('input', '.admin-input', function() {
  $(this).closest('form').addClass('changed');
});
```

```css
.expand1 {
  display: none;
}
.btn1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.expand2 {
  display: none;
}
.btn2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font: 15px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
table#t02,
#t02 th,
#t02 td {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: normal;
}
table#t03,
#t03 th,
#t03 td {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#button1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 85%;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(0, 89, 132);
  font-weight: bold;
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" method="post" class="admin-form">
  <div style="float:left; width:50%">
    <table id="t02" class="table2">
      <tr>
        <th style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"></th>
        <th></th>
        <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0;">Green</th>
        <th colspan="3" style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Yellow</th>
        <th></th>
        <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Red</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="btn1" style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"><b>Collapsible Row1</b>
        </td>
        <td>&lt</td>
        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
          <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>to</td>
        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
          <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>&gt</td>
        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
          <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row1</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row1" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row1" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row1" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row1" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row2</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row2" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row2" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row2" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row2" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row3</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row3" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row3" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row3" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row3" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row4</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row4" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row4" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row4" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row4" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row5</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row5" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row5" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row5" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row5" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row6</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row6" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row6" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row6" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row6" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row7</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row7" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row7" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row7" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row7" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row8</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row8" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row8" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row8" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row8" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row9</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row9" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row9" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row9" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row9" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row10</td>
        <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row10" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row10" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">to</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row10" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand1">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row10" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" id="button1" style="height:50px; width:100px" />
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; width:50%">
    <table id="t03" class="table3">
      <tr>
        <th style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"></th>
        <th></th>
        <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0;">Green</th>
        <th colspan="3" style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Yellow</th>
        <th></th>
        <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Red</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="btn2" style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"><b>Collapsible Row1</b>
        </td>
        <td>&lt</td>
        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
          <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>to</td>
        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
          <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td>&gt</td>
        <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
          <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row1</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row1" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row1" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row1" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row1" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row2</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row2" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row2" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row2" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row2" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row3</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row3" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row3" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row3" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row3" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row4</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row4" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row4" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row4" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row4" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row5</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row5" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row5" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row5" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row5" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row6</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row6" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row6" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row6" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row6" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row7</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row7" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row7" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row7" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row7" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row8</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row8" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row8" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row8" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row8" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row9</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row9" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row9" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row9" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row9" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row10</td>
        <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row10" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row10" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">to</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row10" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
        <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
        <td class="expand2">
          <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row10" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddle300/naL11ram/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your submit button at the bottom of your html code and add the clear property to reset the float.

Like this...

```
        ...
        <div style="width:100%;clear:both">
            <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" id="button1" style="height:50px; width:100px"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/naL11ram/4/

Comment: Thank you ian_sawyer, William Austin and A. R. William and Austin, both your suggestion work perfect for me. ian_sawyer when I tried your suggestion, the button was moving horizontally so I couldn't use it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the submit button to move down when either row is expanded you could move the submit outside of both divs as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/naL11ram/2/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" class="admin-form">
        <div style="float:left; width:50%">
            <table id="t02" class="table2">
                <tr>
                    <th style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0;">Green</th>
                    <th colspan="3" style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Yellow</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Red</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="btn1" style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"><b>Collapsible Row1</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>&lt</td>
                    <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
                        <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td>to</td>
                    <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
                        <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td>&gt</td>
                    <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
                        <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row1</td>
                    <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row1" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row1" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">to</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row1" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row1" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row2</td>
                    <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row2" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row2" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">to</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row2" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row2" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row3</td>
                    <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row3" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row3" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">to</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row3" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row3" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row4</td>
                    <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row4" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row4" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">to</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row4" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row4" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row5</td>
                    <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row5" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row5" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">to</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row5" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row5" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row6</td>
                    <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row6" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row6" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">to</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row6" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row6" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row7</td>
                    <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row7" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row7" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">to</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row7" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row7" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row8</td>
                    <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row8" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row8" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">to</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row8" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row8" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row9</td>
                    <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row9" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row9" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">to</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row9" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row9" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand1">Hidden Row10</td>
                    <td class="expand1">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row10" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row10" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">to</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row10" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand1">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand1">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row10" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; width:50%">
            <table id="t03" class="table3">
                <tr>
                    <th style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0;">Green</th>
                    <th colspan="3" style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Yellow</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th style="padding:0 10px 0 0">Red</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="btn2" style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"><b>Collapsible Row1</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>&lt</td>
                    <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
                        <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td>to</td>
                    <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
                        <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td>&gt</td>
                    <td style="padding:0 10px 0 0">
                        <input type="text" , class="admin-input" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row1</td>
                    <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row1" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row1" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">to</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row1" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row1" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row2</td>
                    <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row2" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row2" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">to</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row2" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row2" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row3</td>
                    <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row3" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row3" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">to</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row3" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row3" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row4</td>
                    <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row4" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row4" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">to</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row4" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row4" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row5</td>
                    <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row5" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row5" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">to</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row5" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row5" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row6</td>
                    <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row6" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row6" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">to</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row6" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row6" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row7</td>
                    <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row7" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row7" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">to</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row7" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row7" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row8</td>
                    <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row8" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row8" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">to</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row8" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row8" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row9</td>
                    <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row9" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row9" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">to</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row9" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row9" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" class="expand2">Hidden Row10</td>
                    <td class="expand2">&lt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_good_high_Hidden Row10" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_low_Hidden Row10" , value="50" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">to</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_warning_high_Hidden Row10" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                    <td class="expand2">&gt</td>
                    <td class="expand2">
                        <input type="text" , name="acd_call_volume_critical_low_Hidden Row10" , value="100" , size="3" , maxlength="3">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div class="button">
            <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" id="button1" style="height:50px; width:100px" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.expand1 {
    display: none;
}
.btn1 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expand2 {
    display: none;
}
.btn2 {
    cursor: pointer;
}
body {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font: 15px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
table#t02, #t02 th, #t02 td {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size:90%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
table#t03, #t03 th, #t03 td {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size:90%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
.button {
    text-align:center;
}
#button1 {
    margin-top:20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(0, 89, 132);
    font-weight: bold;
}
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle
It looks like you just needed a wrapper div around the two tables then put the button outside of the wrapper div

https://jsfiddle.net/naL11ram/1/

This is the begging of your code to change

```
<body>
<form id="form1" method="post" class="admin-form">
<div id="wrapper">
<div style="float:left; width:50%">
<table id="t02" class="table2">
```

This is the end of your code

```
</table>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" id="button1" style="height:50px; width:100px"/>
</form>
```